# How to have a figure right next to an itemize environment, aligned?

Tags: minipage

I'm transcribing lecture notes, and I typically need to have an image to the left, with an itemize to the right (aligned!) I would like to try getting these to work, with no avail.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{minipage-marginpar}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Hello
\item Hello
\item Hello
\item Hello
\item Hello
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

When I try to do so, I get a figure to the left, but the text in the itemize list is further down (not aligned).

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comment your \hfill. It adds some additionnal space and your second minipage does not fit in a single line any more. Or set your minipage length to something smaller.
By the way, I would suggest you to center your image using the c option. And you should use the whole \textwidth in your minipage not to waste space.

```
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Hello
\item Hello
\item Hello
\item Hello
\item Hello
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
```